# ¿Cómo verificar si existe una clave en un diccionario y si existe o no agregarle datos como valor?

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

No se como hacer que segun se repita una clave, en este caso la variable
"taxi_id" se agreguen la clave  "timestamp" en el subdiccionario junto con sus valores respectivs.

Se supone el resultado debe ser este

{ '20000005' : { '1372637482' : '-8.599239:41.149188,-8.584767:41.168529,-8.584317:41.169258,-8.584326:41.169258' }, '20000089' : { '1372639181' : '-8.646534:41.175558,-8.648829:41.177367', '1372639960' : '-8.60418:41.160969,-8.603874:41.1615,-8.579781:41.167881,-8.579763:41.167899' } }

```
def cargarDatos(nombreArchivo):
  f = open(nombreArchivo,"r")
  f.readline()
  dic = {}
  for linea in f:
    lst_datos = linea.strip().split(",")
    polyline = " ".join(lst_datos[7:])
    taxi_id = lst_datos[4]
    timestamp = lst_datos[5]
    dic[taxi_id]={timestamp:polyline}
  return dic
  f.close()
```

nombreArchivo = "taxis.csv"
funcion1 = cargarDatos(nombreArchivo)
print(funcion1)
El archivo es el siguiente:

> TRIP_ID,CALL_TYPE,ORIGIN_CALL,ORIGIN_STAND,TAXI_ID,TIMESTAMP,DAY_TYPE,POLYLINE
> 1372637482620000005,C,,,20000005,1372637482,A,"-8.599239:41.149188,-8.584767:41.168529,-8.584317:41.169258,-8.584326:41.169258" 1372639181620000089,C,,,20000089,1372639181,A,"-8.646534:41.175558,-8.648829:41.177367"
> 1372639960620000309,B,,38,20000089,1372639960,A,"-8.60418:41.160969,-8.603874:41.1615,-8.579781:41.167881,-8.579763:41.167899"

Comment: ¿Has probado el método `get( )`? Ejemplo: `taxi_id.get('valor_de_la_clave')`

Comment: si lees el archivo con pandas y aplicas el método `.to_dict()` todo se vuelve más fácil

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manteniendo el código como lo has expuesto, puedes usar `update` [Latest Python Standard Library Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) también hay un 'shortcut' el cual es `|=`. Pero como `dic[taxi_id]` podría ser nulo y el 'update' tiraría error, entonces:

- Verificación de si 'key' existe:

  - `if dic.get(taxi_id):`
- Agregarle datos:

  - `dic[taxi_id].update({timestamp:polyline})`, ó
  - `dic[taxi_id]|={timestamp:polyline}`

###### update [[Python “extend” for a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577234/python-extend-for-a-dictionary)]

```py
if dic.get(taxi_id):
    dic[taxi_id].update({timestamp:polyline})
else:
    dic[taxi_id]={timestamp:polyline}
```

###### shortcout |= [[What does |= (ior) do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929278/what-does-ior-do-in-python)]

```py
if dic.get(taxi_id):
    dic[taxi_id]|={timestamp:polyline}
else:
    dic[taxi_id]={timestamp:polyline}
```

###### Código

```py
def cargarDatos(nombreArchivo):
  f = open(nombreArchivo,"r")
  f.readline()
  dic = {}
  for linea in f:
    lst_datos = linea.strip().split(",")
    polyline = " ".join(lst_datos[7:])
    taxi_id = lst_datos[4]
    timestamp = lst_datos[5]
    if dic.get(taxi_id):
        dic[taxi_id]|={timestamp:polyline}
    else:
        dic[taxi_id]={timestamp:polyline}
  return dic
  f.close()


nombreArchivo = "taxis.csv"
funcion1 = cargarDatos(nombreArchivo)
print(funcion1)
```

###### Salida

```
{'20000005': 
    {'1372637482': '"-8.599239:41.149188 -8.584767:41.168529 
-8.584317:41.169258 -8.584326:41.169258"'},
'20000089': 
    {'1372639181': '"-8.646534:41.175558 -8.648829:41.177367"',
    '1372639960': '"-8.60418:41.160969 -8.603874:41.1615 -8.579781:41.167881 -8.579763:41.167899"'}}
```

**válido para python 3.9+**

Comment: @Daniela hiciste una pregunta que esta correcta, y te dieron una respuesta mas que valida para tu problema. Si eliminamos todo, nadie mas se beneficia con la respuesta que te dieron, y vos vas a solucionar tu ejercicio con el tiempo que te brindo Alfredo. Si en tu clase consideran que esto es plagio, no es un problema que afecte al sitio. Tene en cuenta que toda pregunta que hagas en el sitio, una vez que esta en el sitio pertenece al sitio.

Answer (score -1):

Para saber si una clave existe o no en un diccionario solo tiene que preguntar por ello con un if clave in diccionario.
Un ejemplo sencillo, he puesto dos if para que se vea bien. Lo único que en lugar de poner claves fijas como he puesto yo pones la variable que contiene la clave y en lugar de print pones el código que quieras si existe y en el else si no existe

```
dic= {1:"a",2:"b",3:"c"}
if 1 in dic:
  print ("Clave existe")
else:
  print ("Clave no existe")
if 4 in dic:
  print("Clave existe")
else:
  print("Clave no existe")
```

Edito mi respuesta ya que visto el voto negativo y el comentario de Ulises Antonio Chávez mi ejemplo no se entiende pese a que he querido mostrar la funcionalidad y no el código específico. Obviamente no se necesita un if por cada clave del diccionario, eso sería totalmente inviable y además de de que si lo que quieres es comprobar las claves evidentemente no las conoces y por tanto no puedes tener preparado un if, también comentar que puse los print a modo de ejemplo, no hay que utilizarlos no sea que alguien piense que con un print  se añaden valores a un diccionario. Teniendo en cuenta que tú clave la pones en una variable que se llama taxi_id y tú diccionario se llama dic el código explicito y con un solo if sería el siguiente.

```
 if taxi_id in dic:
    # Código que necesitas si la clave existe
else:
    # Código que necesitas si la clave no existe
```

Espero que con esta aclaración se entienda que no se necesitan 10000 if, con uno es suficiente. La opción del try también es válida pero usar un control de error para algo que se puede solucionar con UN simple if me parece que es matar moscas a cañonazos.
Un saludo

Comment: Hay formas más óptimas de realizar el código sin poner tantas condicionales, para eso existen los métodos o las funciones, si le pidieran verificar si existen10 mil claves ¿pondrías 10 mil condicionales?

Comment: Un bloque `try/except` podría servir. En el bloque `try` pones `print(dic[valor])`  Y en el `except` pones `print("no existe")`. `valor` es una variable que puede contener cualquier cosa.  En caso exista se imprimirá el resultado y en caso no, dará el mensaje "no existe". 5 líneas de código  \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: @Christian hasta yo me saqué de onda :|

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez jaja, supongo que es mejor representarlo por escrito